# Python twine error: unsupported platform tag 'linux_x86_64'

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I follow [this tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) to create an uploadable python package. The difference is that my package contains a C extension.

The package builds without problem on my linux computer. I get an error when I try to upload the package on test.pypi.org. The error is

```
HTTPError: 400 Bad Request from https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
Binary wheel 'qjson2json-0.0.0-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl' has an unsupported platform tag 'linux_x86_64'.
X
```

From what I found on google, it seam that wheels for specific unix platforms are not supported. It is recommended to use `manylinux` instead. My code is small and a simple C file. Providing precompiled code is not really relevant.

So I  would like to know how I can get around this problem ?

Do I simply erase the .whl file that has been created in dist/ directory ? Or can we specify to only upload the tar.gz file ? In the former case, can we specify to not build the .whl file which is apparently useless ?

Comment: If providing precompiled code is not really relevant then do not upload binary wheels. Upload a source distribution (sdist).

Comment: @phd Indeed. I just found out that I simply need to use the command `python3 -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*.tar.gz` instead of `python3 -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*`. As simple as that.

Comment: Actually you don't need to build wheels at all: `python setup.py sdist` is enough. See https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#source-distributions

Comment: @phd Will that command work if I have many other files (e.g. setup.cfg) ? I used the command `python3 -m build`. Is it possible to specify with this command that we only want source distribution ?

Comment: Nop, not with `build`; source distribution is the result of `sdist`.